# Sorting a Dictionary by Key and then Value (list or tuple?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, bioinformatics

I have a dictionary

```
dict = {key: [a, b, c, d]}
```

key is a str, a is a number, b is a number, c is a number, d is a number.

How do I print my dictionary sorted first by the number in d, ***and then*** by the length of the string in key (largest first)?

I tried using something like this...

```
for key in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda x: (-len(x[0]), x[1][3])):
```

but I keep getting attribute errors.

Comment: What is the exact error message (edit the questions to show it as properly formatted text)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted code doesn't execute due to undefined variables.

Comment: `sorted(your_dict.items(), key=lambda t: (t[1][-1], len(t[0])))`

Comment: @dawg: They want longest key first (for equal `d`), so add a `-` to make it `-len(t[0])`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Yes -- I fixed that in my answer. Thanks!

Comment: The code you show should *not* have given a key error, so there's something you're not telling us. Do all the items in your dict have at least 4 elements?

Comment: @dawg I obviously didnt actually name my dictionary dict. I was just using it as an example.

Comment: @asttra: You say "obviously", but people do this all the time, and then get confused when they try to use the `dict` constructor and get `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable` because they shadowed the built-in `dict` with their own instance of `dict`. Just search StackOverflow for `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable` and you'll see this problem (sometimes with `dict`, sometimes with other names, like `sorted`, `input`, etc.) over, and over, and over, and over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something along the line of this:

```
>>> dictionary = {'aaaa': [1,2,2,3], 'aa': [1,2,2,3], 'aaa': [2,2,2,2], 'a': [4,2,2,6]}
>>> arr = sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1][3],-len(x[0])))
>>> for k in arr:
        print(k)

('a', [4, 2, 2, 6])
('aaaa', [1, 2, 2, 3])
('aa', [1, 2, 2, 3])
('aaa', [2, 2, 2, 2])
```

Note: sort by larger `d` first, then longer `key` first.

To reverse the ordering, of any priorities, simply experimenting with removing/leaving `-` in the elements in the tupple in the `lambda` function.

Comment: I don't he meant descending order of `d`. The descending order constraint only applies to the key string length.

Comment: @slider Yes, just updated the answer :P the ordering choice is arbitrary, this is a proof-of-concept rather than a fool-proof solution :D

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries are unordered collections unless you are using Python 3.6+. Therefore, I assume you want to construct an `OrderedDict` according to your 2 criteria. For this you can use `sorted` with a custom key and then feed to `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {'ads': [4, 6, 1, 4], 'bs': [1, 3, 1, 9], 'cfsdg': [6, 1, 5, 4], 'ddsf': [5, 1, 6, 4]}

res = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1][-1], -len(x[0]))))

OrderedDict([('cfsdg', [6, 1, 5, 4]),
             ('ddsf', [5, 1, 6, 4]),
             ('ads', [4, 6, 1, 4]),
             ('bs', [1, 3, 1, 9])])
```

Comment: The OP doesn't need the `dict` itself sorted. They just want to print it in sorted order. There is no need for `OrderedDict` here.

Comment: @ShadowRanger "Print my dict sorted" is a phrase I find ambiguous. You could say it's different to "Print a sorted dict", but the adjective can in fact be arbitrarily before or after the object in such a phrase.

Answer (score 0):

(Shamelessly stealing jpp's example dict)

You can do:

```
di = {'ads': [4, 6, 1, 4], 'bs': [1, 3, 1, 9], 'cfsdg': [6, 1, 5, 4], 'ddsf': [5, 1, 6, 4]}
print('\n'.join(map(str, sorted(di.items(), key=lambda t: (t[1][-1], -len(t[0]))))))
```

Prints:

```
('cfsdg', [6, 1, 5, 4])
('ddsf', [5, 1, 6, 4])
('ads', [4, 6, 1, 4])
('bs', [1, 3, 1, 9])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, but probably not the "right" behavior you're looking for because you have the wrong negative signs. You're probably doing something wrong with your "key" variable, because when you do sorted with `dict.items()` it's returning you a tuple with `(key, value)`

This is a longshot, but my guess is that you're trying to do this?

```
for key in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda x: (-len(x[0]), x[1][3])):
    print(dict[key])
```

This is not correct since "key" returns a tuple.

To do this in a way that's easier for you to understand, would be the following.

```
for key, value in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1][-1], -len(x[0]))):
    print(key, value)
```

Why does it return a list of tuples? Because `dict.items()` is a list of tuples, and you are sorting that list of tuples, not a dictionary object.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your dictionary intact and sort it, use the `dict()` constructor

```
d = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1][3], -len(x[0]))))
# {'stampede': [4, 2, 1, 1], 'the': [3, 3, 2, 1], 'vash': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```